# Using breakpoint package: "Error in data: dataframe only"

Tags: r, breakpoints

I am using the breakpoint package to detect breakpoints in my data. 
This is my code so far:

```
library(breakpoint)
CE.NB(df1$count, Nmax = 10)
```

But when running the code, it gives me this error:

**"Error in data: dataframe only"**

I check my df1 which is a data frame:

```
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   18 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date: Date, format: "2012-07-01" "2012-08-01" "2012-09-01" "2012-10-01" ...
 $ count        : num  2.33 1.35 1.53 2.14 2.85 ...
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: you are passing a vector to `CE.NB` (`df1$count`) which is not a data.frame: `str(df1$count`)

Comment: You must pass a data.frame (or matrix). You are passing a vector. Try `CE.NB(df1[, "count", drop = FALSE], Nmax = 10)`.

Comment: @Roland this worked, thanks!